# why doesn't rendering image work

Tags: javascript, html

Following the example from this [html2canvas example](http://jsfiddle.net/alperenozlu/sodofkcs/), I am trying to make it possible to turn the content from textarea into an image.

The following code doesn't work. With the textarea containing `<h2>Hi you</h2>`, clicking "to image" button produces an empty image.  Interestingly, if I change the first line in function `takeScreenShot` to be `document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = "<h2>you</h2"`, then the image is produced.  Wonder why.

```
<html><head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

</head><body>
<!-- from http://jsfiddle.net/alperenozlu/sodofkcs/ -->
<textarea cols="80" rows="15" id="input">
</textarea><br/>
<div id="target">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>

<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
<script>
takeScreenShot = function() {
    document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input").value;
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        },
        width:320,
        height:220
    });
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Any errors in your browser console?

Comment: @Amy, no, the console is squeaking clean :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `width` and `height` properties and got it to work.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  </head>
   <body>
   <!-- from http://jsfiddle.net/alperenozlu/sodofkcs/ -->
    <textarea cols="80" rows="15" id="input">
    </textarea><br/>
    <div id="target">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>

    <button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
    <script>
      takeScreenShot = function() {
          document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input").value;
          html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
              onrendered: function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
              }
          });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```